# Align button to the bottom (float)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the button in the following image to the bottom, I've tried a lot of tricks but nothing seems to work without breaking it. The button is to take up a fixed space while the textarea is to fill the remaining space. Added codepen example!

Would like a non flexbox answer (ie9+)! Also only LESS as a preprocessor if not vanilla css.

[image]

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">

    <div class="right">
      <button>submit</button>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

css:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.text {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

js:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  theme: 'modern',
  width: '100%',
  height: 50,
  autoresize_min_height: 50,
  menubar: false, // removes top menubar,
  statusbar: false, // removes bottom statusbar
  toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | link image',
  plugins: ['image autoresize'],
  automatic_uploads: false,
});
```

http://codepen.io/basickarl/pen/Megjyb

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is your friend:
http://codepen.io/mwvanmeurs/pen/XKrRKx

Made `.text` a flex container and told everything to align to the end of it.

Take a look at the CSS there and lmk if you have any questions. 
To highlight the differences:

```
.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Doh! Forgot to mention that no flexbox (ie9+, damn I keep forgetting to mention this) is being used, I will 1+ you for the effort, it might help some other poor soul :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case to use CSS tables.

- Set the wrapper element `.text` to `display: table;`.
- Set the child *"column"* elements `.left` and `.right` to `display: table-cell;`.
- Set `.right` to `vertical-align: bottom;` to shift the content to the bottom instead of the middle or top.

Not sure if you needed the gray background so I removed it. Might need to double check some padding also.

```css
.text {
  display: table;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}
.right,
.left {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
}
.right {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.left {
  width: 100%;
}
```

- Updated [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRbVor) with fixed width for `.text` (`800px`).
- Updated [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKrgNb) with percentage width for `.text` (`80%`).

Comment: Would work, however the size of the button will vary as "submit" will vary with language, one language might have the equivalent to a 10 letter word, so the 88% wouldn't work :( Hence the weight I put on it not breaking

Comment: @KarlMorrison I had a feeling you'd say that. You could adjust the width per language. It's obviously a little more work but you could add a language class to `.wrapper` or `.text`. Something like `.wrapper.en { width: 88%; }`, `.wrapper.es { width: 85%; }` and  `.wrapper.fr { width: 90%; }`; Not pretty, but an option.

Comment: I don't think it will ever be able to cover all screens and all screen dpi's etc.  :(

Comment: You're using fixed widths (i.e. `800px` for `.text`). Unless you're going to convert that to a relative value I'm not sure where being concerned about various screen sizes comes in along with DPI. Relative units like percentages are a good way to go if you're looking for responsive design. Though I do have a **new solution** for you. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.right {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top:20%;
  background: gray;
}
```

[image]

Comment: instead of using height : 100% in the .right class ..use margin-top:20%;

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

**Option 1**

Give the button an ID, for example:

```
#button-submit{
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: bottom;
 }
```

and the add two simple styles

```
#button-submit{
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: bottom;
 }
```

**Option 2**

The other option is you set the text div to have a fixed height that suits the size of the ***text-area***. You've used ***height: 200px*** for your ***#text*** div. So you might want to combat it like this...

```
#text{
   width: 800px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: red;
   height: 200px;
} 


#right button{
    height: 30px;
    margin: 170px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

What that will do is push down the button without giving it an ID. This works as long as you don't want anything else above the submit button to the right of the text field.

Answer (score 0):

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/ph110293/pen/oLvwNz)

```
.right {
 position:absolute;
 float: right;
 padding: 10px;
 background: gray;
 height: 20px;
 width: 50px;
 bottom:0px;
 right:0px;
  }



.text {
  position:relative;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
 }

.wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: green;
 }


.left {
 overflow: auto;
 padding: 10px;
 width:91%;
 }
```

This should work for you.